# Does the version of VS affect opening solutions

Tags: visual-studio, version, visual-studio-2012

I have searched on Google for this, but have had no luck.

I currently have the enterprise edition of VS2012 (paid by my company). If/when I leave the company I assume I will also lose the license and may have to return to the Express version.

I assume the answer is no, but, will there be any problem loading any of projects in a 'downgraded' version of VS2012? I assume all I will lose is the features VS enterprise offers but my project will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me, most valuable limitations of Express versions are

- no resource editor
- no remote debugger
- does not supports folders in solutions, but projects from folder will be accessible, they just will be displayed in the root of solution, rather in folder.

Thought, there much more limitations, but you may not afraid, Express will open your solutions.

Comment: Also VS express does not support every project type you find in VS "full"

Comment: I was not thinking about languages, but more about things like VSTO for instance, which won't work in any express edition